# How to position widgets inline in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve something like this in Android:
[image: spinner within two textviews]

which is a `Spinner` between two `TextView` widgets, aligned by baseline within `RelativeLayout`.

So far looks fine, as long as everything fits into one line. The tricky part is having it wrapped if there's too much text (e.g. i18n), or the screen is too small — and RelativeLayout is powerless here, the line simply overflows the screen.

Basically I need something like "display: inline; vertical-align: baseline" in HTML. Any ideas how to achieve this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For text size use sp as size parameter. Rest give spinner size in dp. It will automatically adjust.